Does database compound index order matter if the first column is only queried with an equal operation?
Question: assuming I have an Orders table with an index (UserId, CreatedTime), does it matter if I add DESC to CreatedTime if I want to list orders by a single user only?
For example:
SELECT * 
FROM Orders -- Also potentially have row limit
WHERE UserId = @UserId
ORDER BY CreatedTime DESC; 

What I do not understand is that, if the answer is yes, why can't the DB simply start at the bottom and go up since it knows the range of @UserId already?
Also I work with both SQL Server and SQLite so I would appreciate to know if the answer would be different for each DBMS.
I still do not really understand SQL Server indexes - ascending or descending, what difference does it make? and apparently in MongoDB,
it doesn't matter (Does order of indexes matter in MongoDB?).
Back to the above query, even if I was to list all users and their corresponding orders in descending CreatedTime, why can't the database do this:

For user #1, their rows is from #1 to #10, so fetch rows #1 to #10 in reverse order.
For user #2 their rows is from #11 to #13, so fetch rows #11 to #13 in reverse order.
...

I even asked AI and it simply told me it's slower to fetch from bottom up without further explanation even when I tried to press it for one.

When you tested, and inspected the query plans, what did you discover?

In SQL Server it doesn't make much difference here. The index leaf pages are a doubly linked list and so it can be traversed in either forward or backward direction. Backward can't be parallelised though. If you look at the execution plan it will tell you if in the properties of the seek operator (assuming you get one with *) if it is Ordered and the scan direction if so.

@ThomA sorry I am not really a database designer but mainly a .NET programmer but sometimes DB design is part of my job. I do not really have the tool and knowledge to benchmark them. From my .NET app, no significant difference can be observed but then I think the data from my tests are too "perfect".

@MartinSmith ah I see parallelism cited as a reason in the linked article. Sorry as a programmer only it's just hard for me to understand why going backwards is any different than going forward. I guess there is a good reason why they do not do that.

I think the only reason is that they never got around to implementing it. So not a particularly good reason

You should only ask about 1 RDBMS per question.

Note that a backwards scan that @MartinSmith refers to is always the opposite direction of the index. So if the index is DESC and the query is DESC that's not the opposite direction. Only if the query and index are different.

In SQLite, the index will be used whether you sort by CreatedTime ascending or descending.
Given:
create table orders (
  user_id integer,
  created_time integer
);

create index orders_index on orders (user_id, created_time);

The query plans for both sorts are identical:
sqlite> explain query plan select * from orders where user_id = 1 order by created_time;
QUERY PLAN
`--SEARCH orders USING COVERING INDEX orders_index (user_id=?)

sqlite> explain query plan select * from orders where user_id = 1 order by created_time desc;
QUERY PLAN
`--SEARCH orders USING COVERING INDEX orders_index (user_id=?)

If instead you're doing a range query on user_id and then sorting by user_id, created_time, an additional temporary table will be used only if created_time is sorted in descending order:
sqlite> explain query plan select * from orders where user_id > 1 order by user_id, created_time;
QUERY PLAN
`--SEARCH orders USING COVERING INDEX orders_index (user_id>?)

sqlite> explain query plan select * from orders where user_id > 1 order by user_id, created_time desc;
QUERY PLAN
|--SEARCH orders USING COVERING INDEX orders_index (user_id>?)
`--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR LAST TERM OF ORDER BY

For this query, you'll need an index for created_time desc:
create index orders_index_2 on orders (user_id, created_time desc);

=>
sqlite> explain query plan select * from orders where user_id > 1 order by user_id, created_time desc;
QUERY PLAN
`--SEARCH orders USING COVERING INDEX orders_index_2 (user_id>?)


That's very interesting. Thanks to you I know the explain query plan query. Still I am curious why a temp table is needed.

A temporary table is needed for where user_id > 1 order by user_id, created_time desc because the index is on user_id, created_time (both ascending) and you're asking for results in a different order user_id asc, created_time desc. The database engine will be scanning forward to find user_id > 1 and so the created_time will also be ascending which needs to be fixed with another sort.

Note that if you ask for both columns in descending order, the temporary table disappears from the query plan: select * from orders where user_id > 1 order by user_id desc, created_time desc because the database can now do a reverse scan on that index.

What, that's so weird lol. Sorry it makes no sense to me. If it could scan upwards (for when both have DESC), why can't it scan upwards for CreatedTime only when it knows exactly where each UserId is?

@LukeVo the index is sorted by user_id asc, created_time asc. If you traverse it forward, you get both ascending, if you traverse it backwards, you get both descending, but you cannot traverse with one value ascending and one descending. Note that the index will be used for asc + desc query to filter users, but to sort the second column descending, a temporary table will need to be used.
